# Firefox 33 network activity is suddenly extremely slow on 14.04

Tags: firefox

**Problem**: I use Firefox as my default browser constantly. It was working just fine yesterday for most of the day. However, when I came home in the evening and fired up the computer, browsing the internet with Firefox was agonizing. I'm talking like 10-20 seconds to load pages that are loading almost instantly on Chrome on the same computer.

I do note that sometimes a page will load almost instantly as it should, but then subsequent assets on that page and further page loads will go back to taking a long time.

**Background**: I'm a software developer and have used Linux for years.  I'm running Firefox 33 on Ubuntu 14.04. I've tried all the usual things to fix this problem including:

- safe mode
- creating a new and fresh Firefox profile for testing
- disabling http proxy in settings
- restarted firefox and the computer
- can use Chrome without problems, ruling out general networking/internet speed issues

I did apply some pending Ubuntu updates yesterday.  Unfortunately, I'm not sure what updates they were or if it is really related to this at all.

I would so appreciate *any* help or suggestions.  I'm just beginning to realize how much of my daily workflow is dependent on Firefox!

Answer (score 1):

I realized that the problem was DNS settings on my system.  For some reason, my `resolv.conf` settings didn't switch when I joined my home network and contained two nameserver entries that didn't exist on this network.  The third nameserver in `resolv.conf` worked.  As soon as I removed the first two and left just the good nameserver, this problem went away.